# Prometheus query to count unique label values over a period

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to calc the total distinct label counts over a period time.

Eg. I have below 4 sample data

Metrics   Labels                                       TimeStamp     Values

```
cpu_usage{instance="192.168.100.10:20001",job="node2"}@1646225640 => 4
cpu_usage{instance="192.168.100.10:20001",job="node1"}@1646225700 => 5
cpu_usage{instance="192.168.100.10:20001",job="node3"}@1646225760 => 3
cpu_usage{instance="192.168.100.10:20001",job="node2"}@1646225820 => 4
```

So if I check startdate=1646225640, enddate=1646225700, I got 2 distinct jobs, which are node2 and node1

if I check startdate=1646225640, end date=1646225820, I got 3 distinct jobs, which are node1, node2, and node3.

Is there a way in promql can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Find one way to achieve this

```
count by (job_temp) (count_over_time(cpu_usage[1h]))
```

or

```
sum(count by (job) (count_over_time(cpu_usage[1h])))
```

PromQL is a time-series based so I find it more useful to illustrate with image:

[image]

say we want to check between 1646225640 and 1646225820

prometheus data is based on metrics{labels} for a series of timestamp, so count_over_time will return results with 3 records:

instance=192.168.100.10:20001,job=node1 values=[[1646225700, 1]]
instance=192.168.100.10:20001,job=node2 values=[[1646225640, 1], [1646225820, 1]]
instance=192.168.100.10:20001,job=node3 values=[[1646225760, 1]]

for above results, if we count by job, it's like group by job, so we have 3 results too

if we count by labels that doesn't exist in the metrics, then prometheus will just take no label as group by filter, then we will only have 1 result cause they haven't been grouped at all, which is the second query sum method effect

Answer (score 0):

The following PromQL query should return unique `job` label values for the metric `cpu_usage` on a time range `(t-d ... t]`:

```
count(last_over_time(cpu_usage[d] @ t)) by (job)
```

This query uses the following PromQL features:

- [count()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#group) aggregate function for counting the number of time series per each unique `job` value.
- [last_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) rollup function, which returns the last value per each time series on the given lookbehind window `d` in square brackets.
- [@ modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#modifier) for executing the query at the given timestamp `t`.

The query can be simplified if it is executed in [recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) or [alerting rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/). For example, the following query counts the number of unique time series per each unique `job` label value for the last hour:

```
count(last_over_time(cpu_usage[1h])) by (job)
```